# How to fix keyboard shortcut toggle for keyboard layout?

Tags: gnome, 13.10, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I use both German and US American layout. For convenience, I defined a shortcut to toggle these via <kbd>Scroll</kbd>. I also have an indicator on the top gnome shell bar that shows the current layout.

Yet recently, I assume it has something to do with the 13.10 upgrade, pressing the shortcut does not toggle the layout in the current application even though the indicator shows the change. Strangely, going into the keyboard applet via mouse and there selecting the layout works.

How do I get the keyboard shortcut working again?

Answer (score 0):

This is a confirmed bug; you can apply the [beta patch](https://launchpad.net/~attente/+archive/1218322), or try an alternate desktop like kubuntu.